# Webpack: Why there are multiple files with same file name when search the source code?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, webpack-5

I am using vue.js (2.6.5) and webpack (5.77.1), and I enabled the source map feature in development env, with simple config as below:

```
mode: 'development',
devtool: 'eval-cheap-module-source-map',
.....
```

Well, the source map feature indeed works, but what confuse me is when you search a file name, there will be multiple files with same file name listed, see as below:
[image: searched file list]

Only one of them is the exact original file definition, other files are definitions of render function of vue.js and some others. Every time I need to click on each one of them to check which is the exact original file, this annoys me, does any one know how to only show the exact original file ?

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example? It is impossible to confirm without examining the generated bundle by Webpack.

Comment: Did you get a fix for the above issue. I am also getting the same issue